# How can I programmatically close/cancel react-native-app-auth's authorize webview in React Native App?

Tags: react-native, authentication, webview

I am using a [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) library to authorize the users in a React Native app. Calling [authorize()](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#authorize) opens a webview where the user can then input their credentials to log in. This webview also has a Cancel button that closes the webview and returns the user to the app. I am trying to implement a timeout that will automatically close the authorize webview after a certain amount of time. Is there a way I could achieve this programmatically?

I was hoping to find any APIs to manually trigger a redirected to the app but no luck